# Can we view messages from the console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have several apps now sending FCM messages back and forth.  Is there anyway I can view the messages from my firebase console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest updates to the [notifications dashboard](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/reporting) in the Firebase console, you can see a report of sends, opens, and impressions for notifications as well as information about data messages for iOS and Android. You cannot, however, see the specific content of messages. You could probably build some sort of logging server-side if you wanted to track this.